# 204 "No Content" Response on Failing DELETE Request

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

We're currently testing a Microsoft Graph API integration that works with the Calendar created in Bookings. We aren't running off the Bookings API as it is still in preview and lacks certain data points, but rather interfacing directly with the underlying calendar as it works and syncs properly with Bookings, as long as you stick to basic operation such as GETS and DELETES.

We ran into an odd scenario in which the Graph API returns a 204 NO CONTENT status on a failing DELETE request. The user being tested has REVIEWER folder permissions on the calendar. When a DELETE request goes out, the event does not delete (as intended with someone who only had REVIEWER permissions), however the response received is a 204 NO CONTENT response, which should only be returning upon a successful request according to the [Graph API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Sample:

```
//Signed in user is listed a REVIEWER on calendar
REQUEST: DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/events/{id}
RESPONSE: 204 NO CONTENT //Even though calendar event remains
```

Is this an issue with the Graph API or do I need to get permissions issues for failed requests another way? Seems wrong it would show successful for a failed request, but I know things may get weird working with the underlying calendar.

Comment: I have created an event both using the graph api and through calendar and deleted them successfully. Can you please check if you are deleting the events created by you or not?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity You should not be able to create or delete events with "Reviewer" permissions set on the account? Can you test again with correct permissions? The event should not delete, but it will still give you a `204 NO CONTENT` response vs an expected failure response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache and cookies, and then re-execute the request.

I think there is something wrong with your request URL, please change to:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendar/events/{id}
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars/{id}/events/{id}
```

After my test, it can work well for me.

Comment: Request URL is correct per spec. It calls the users default calendar, where as your call allows for other calendars within the profile. Clearing cache had no effect. What response code did you receive and can you confirm the tested account did not have permissions to delete?

Comment: @Tronald  I received a 204 response. When I delete it, I will no longer be able to retrieve it, so I am sure it has been deleted. When I try to use the request url you provided, it returned me a 404.

Comment: You should not be able to delete it? Are you sure you are testing an account with reviewer permissions? As for the 404 that is strange as it works for me and is listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @Tronald  I did not see the request url in the documentation you provided:  `DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{calendar}/events/{id}`

Comment: Oh Gosh `{Calendar}` is supposed to be `{id | userPrincipleName}` within the url my apologies. That was just a typo in the question good catch, but I was passing correctly in the test. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipleName}/events/{id}`